# Using FVWM on Linux, do I need the "DragWell" extension to drag and drop photos?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, google-plus, fvwm

I have photos on my hard drive that I would like to upload to Google Plus using drag and drop.  But drag and drop does nothing.  I don't know which of the following parties are to blame:

- Image viewer (I tried Image Magick and quiver)
- Window manager (mine is FVWM, which I have been using for a long, long time—reluctant to switch)
- Web browser (Linux version of Google Chrome)

I'd be happy to use any image viewer I could get to work.  (F-Spot, which is my favorite, crashes.)  But I really prefer to stick with Chrome and with FVWM.  Searching suggests that perhaps an FVWM extension is needed for drag and drop, but I can't make sense of what I am reading.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the drag and drop you refer to here is not under FVWM's control -- what you've read refers to the FvwmDragWell, which has nothing to do with what you're after.